# tax_query not working for taxonomy slug

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

i have one custom post type 'game' and one custom taxonomy 'console', which is shared by 'game' and 'post'. Now I created a new PHP 'taxonomy-console' and I want to separately display posts from 'post' on the left and posts from 'game' on the right.

the code I am using is:

```
    <?php  $slug = $term->slug; 
           $query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'order'=>'DESC', 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'console', 'field'    => 'slug', 'terms'    => $slug, ), ), ) );
                if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    /* bla bla bla */
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

But neither this nor **'post_type' => 'game'** are displaying anything.

The thing is, I am using the same exact code on another taxonomy page, the only difference is that it is registered with only one post_type and doesn't share two post types.

Comment: your array is missing a comma before `tax_query`, do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: sorry, just made the mistake while writing the code here. that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: where do you set `$term`? have you verified that contains what you expect? you can `var_dump($query)` and see how the query vars are being set and the SQL being sent to the DB.

Comment: isn't `$term` already predefined in taxonomy php?

Comment: the thing is, if I put the slug of one specific term in the `'terms'`, then it displays the posts, but  I want it to retrieve the slugs automatically for each term

Comment: you can get the current term object via [`get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) or its ID via [`get_queried_object_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment so I have to provide an answer which I don't have a full answer.  If I were you I would print_r($slug) and see what it gives you.  The $slug variable is most likely not in a format that 'terms' can accept.

Comment: Ok so i tried that and it displayed nothing, so i used @Milo's `get_queried_object_id` and then it displayed the ID, so thanks to both of you so much !!!